# FreeBSD snd_hda configuring audio device

Tags: drivers, freebsd, audio, intel

I have a Macbook Pro 11,3 with it's sound hardware on FreeBSD. With some help I was able to configure my hardware to have headphone output but internal speakers just does not work. Here is my original verbose boot.

```
kernel: hdaa1: nid   0x    as seq device       conn  jack    loc        color   misc
kernel: hdaa1: 16 002b4020 2  0  Headphones    Jack  Combo   0x00       Green   0
kernel: hdaa1: 17 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 18 90100110 1  0  Speaker       Fixed Unknown Internal   Unknown 1
kernel: hdaa1: 19 90100112 1  2  Speaker       Fixed Unknown Internal   Unknown 1
kernel: hdaa1: 20 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 21 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 22 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 23 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 24 00ab9040 4  0  Mic           Jack  Combo   0x00       Pink    0
kernel: hdaa1: 25 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 26 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 27 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 28 90a60100 0  0  Mic           Fixed Digital Internal   Unknown 1
kernel: hdaa1: 29 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 30 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 31 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 32 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
kernel: hdaa1: 33 004be030 3  0  SPDIF-out     Jack  Combo   0x00       White   0
kernel: hdaa1: 34 400000f0 15 0  Line-out      None  Unknown 0x00       Unknown 0
```

I was able to edit and make these associations

```
hint.hdac.1.cad0.nid18.config="as=1 seq=0"
hint.hdac.1.cad0.nid19.config="as=1 seq=2"
```

that gives me headphone audio but.... I would like to have audio working best as possible.

I've been reading the [snd_hda documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?snd_hda(4)) but boy, it's really dense and I am really not understanding this too well.

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the startup log for `pcm` devices. They should carry some indication of what they refer to.

You can select the pcm device you want to use by setting the sysctl:
    `hw.snd.default_unit`
to the correct pcm number. It should then spring into life.